# IndexError: list index out of range for 2D list of objects

Tags: python, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

Here's my code:

```
class Grid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.matrix = [[Cell(i, j)] for j in range(5) for i in range(6)]
    
    # Extra stuff

    def enter_letter(self, letter):
        if self.current_col == 5:
            return
        
        print(self.matrix[0][1].get_letter()) # Test, this is where it goes wrong.
        # It also goes wrong when I call set_letter() a 2nd time as it goes to matrix[0][1] in the line below:
        self.matrix[self.current_row][self.current_col].set_letter(letter)
        self.current_col += 1

    # Extra stuff

class Cell:
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
    
    # Extra stuff
```

And the thing is, every time I try to access or call `set_letter()` on `self.matrix[0][1]`, it gives me the IndexError: list index out of range. It's completely fine when I try to access matrix[4][0] but anything above a 0 for the y value, throws me an index error. I tried Googling and a lot of the suggestions was to call `.append()` to each list to make it a 2D list (not sure if I explained that right) so I tried but I found it difficult to apply to a list of objects...

If I could get any suggestions at all, that would be great :)

Comment: you need to put your row or column inside the 2nd dimension of the array. So `self.matrix = [[Cell(i,j) for i in range(5)] for j in range(6)]` or vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TheLazyScripter suggested, here's the code I changed to make it work:

```
class Grid:
    def __init__(self):
        self.matrix = [[Cell(i, j) for i in range(6)] for j in range(5)]
```